# IIS7 URL Rewrite, how this work if value coming from DB

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am looking into using IIS7 URL Rewrite for an app I am working.

At the moment my URLs look like this:

```
overview.aspx?orgId=2121
```

Where each `orgId` would have an organisation name.

I'd like my URL to look like this:

```
/OrgName/Overview
/Microsoft/Overview
```

Is it possible to write this kind of rule in IIS7, where it would have to look up the ID from the database get the name value for the org and then append to organisation ?

I would also need to store these friendly URLs in my DB, or would IIS automatically switch to friendly URLs if someone typed `overview.aspx?orgId=2121` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to implement your own custom provider to do that.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/